# how to use app_controller function in component cakephp 1.3

Tags: cakephp-1.3

i have a component class

```
class ChimagesUploadComponent extends Object{
```

/***************************************************
    * fileModel is the name of the model used if we want to 
    *  keep records of uploads in a database.
    * 
    * if you don't wish to use a database, simply set this to null
    *  $this->FileUpload->fileModel = null;
    *
    * @var mixed
    * @access public
    */

var $fileModel = 'Image';

/***************************************************
    * uploadDir is the directory name in the webroot that you want
    * the uploaded files saved to.  default: files which means
    * webroot/files must exist and set to chmod 777
    *
    * @var string
    * @access public
    */

var $uploadDir = 'chimages';

and function in 
app_controller

```
function getCurrentUser() {
```

App::import('Component','Session');
  $Session = new SessionComponent();

$user = $Session->read('Auth.User');

return $user;
}

i want to use this function in my class ChimagesUploadComponent.

the reason is i want to save the images in different folder retrieving the folder name from
the function and saving it accordingly i tried with concatinating

in class ChimagesUploadComponent.
i did

```
 $user=$this->getCurrentUser();
$logid = $user['district_id'];
```

and then tried to concatenate it in

```
var $uploadDir = 'chimages/'.$logid;
```

as i have different folders in webroot/chimages/12 webroot/chimages/13 etc. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to pass value in argument during the calling of component from controller.

But if you still want to access the Application Controller method then just call using

```
AppController::getCurrentUser()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may be the another way to do this is

```
$Appcontroller= new AppController();
$Appcontroller->calltoanyfunction();
```

And in this way you can call any controller's function into another one.